# How to use @ syntax in Emmet 2.0?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

This worked in in older Emmet of VS Code but not in the newer one. Is there a different syntax for this?

[image]

This is its output, same as Intellisense.

[image]

Comment: What is the `vscode` version you are trying it on?

Comment: 1.13.1 stable release

Comment: Very strange. I wonder how it works on mine. Are you using vscode's default emmet plugin? or a third party one?

Comment: I'm using  vscode's default plugin

Comment: What do you get when you hit the Tab key? Doesn't it do anything? Can you update your question with your output?

Comment: It gives me same output as shown by Intellisense

Comment: I guess there's some interference from one the plugins you have installed. I tried on Mac/Windows just now. it works perfectly

Comment: Disabled all extensions in VS Code, still didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented in new Emmet